# OpenSSL 3.0 Create EC Private Key in PEM Format from Private Key in mpi representation

Tags: c, openssl, public-key-encryption

I want to update a function which should generate an EC Private Key in PEM format to OpenSSL 3.0. Most of the EC functions that are used are now deprecated. Below you can see the deprecated function.

```c
ERR Security_GetECKey(KeyPairECType enKeyPairECType, const unsigned char *puchKey, unsigned int uiLength, char **ppstPEMKey)
{
    ERR err;
    int iNID;
    BIGNUM *pBigNumPrivate;
    BN_CTX *pBigNumCtx;
    EC_KEY *pEcKey;
    EC_POINT *pEcPoint;
    const EC_GROUP *pEcGroup;
    EVP_PKEY *pEVPPKey;
    int iBIOLength;
    BIO *pBIOOut;
    const unsigned char *puchPEMKey;

    err = ERR_NONE;

    if((enKeyPairECType > KeyPairECType_Max) ||
       (ppstPEMKey == NULL) ||
       (uiLength == 0) ||
       (puchKey == NULL))
    {
        err = Err_Code(ERR_INVALID_PARAM);
    }
    else
    {
        switch(enKeyPairECType)
        {
            case KeyPairECType_NID_SECP521r1:
                iNID = NID_secp521r1;
                break;
            default:
                iNID = 0;
                err = Err_Code(ERR_INVALID_PARAM);
                break;
        }

        if(err == ERR_NONE)
        {
            THREAD_LOCK_LIB_TOOLS();
            /*
             * Use length from mpi header + 4. instead of length of whole char array.
             * Length of char array (uiLength) could be longer than mpi
             */
            pBigNumPrivate = BN_mpi2bn((unsigned char*)puchKey, ((puchKey[0]<<24) | (puchKey[1]<<16) | (puchKey[2]<<8) | puchKey[3]) + 4, NULL);
            if(pBigNumPrivate != NULL)
            {
                pBigNumCtx = BN_CTX_new();
                if(pBigNumCtx != NULL)
                {
                    /*
                     * TODO: The low-level EC_KEY_... API functions are deprecated with OpenSSL 3.0!
                     * Ignore the warnings for now until the source code is adapted to use
                     * the appropriate high-level APIs.
                     */
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
                    pEcKey = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(iNID);
                    if(pEcKey != NULL)
                    {
                        pEcGroup = EC_KEY_get0_group(pEcKey);
                        if(pEcGroup != NULL)
                        {
                            pEcPoint = EC_POINT_new(pEcGroup);
                            if(pEcPoint != NULL)
                            {
                                if(EC_KEY_set_private_key(pEcKey, pBigNumPrivate) != FALSE)
                                {
                                    if(EC_POINT_mul(pEcGroup, pEcPoint, pBigNumPrivate, NULL, NULL, pBigNumCtx) != FALSE)
                                    {
                                        if(EC_KEY_set_public_key(pEcKey, pEcPoint) != FALSE)
                                        {
                                            pEVPPKey = EVP_PKEY_new();
                                            if(pEVPPKey != NULL)
                                            {
                                                if(EVP_PKEY_set1_EC_KEY(pEVPPKey, pEcKey) != FALSE)
                                                {
                                                    pBIOOut = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
                                                    if(pBIOOut != NULL)
                                                    {
                                                        gstPassword = NULL;
                                                        if((PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey(pBIOOut, pEVPPKey, NULL, NULL, 0, Security_PEM_Password_CB, NULL)) == 0)
                                                        {
                                                            err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            iBIOLength = BIO_get_mem_data(pBIOOut, &puchPEMKey);
                                                            if(iBIOLength > 0)
                                                            {
                                                                err = Mem_AllocEx((void **)ppstPEMKey, (iBIOLength + 1) * sizeof(char));
                                                                if(err == ERR_NONE)
                                                                {
                                                                    memcpy(*ppstPEMKey, puchPEMKey, iBIOLength);
                                                                    (*ppstPEMKey)[iBIOLength] = '\00';
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                            else
                                                            {
                                                                err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
                                                            }

                                                        }
                                                        BIO_free(pBIOOut);
                                                    }
                                                    EVP_PKEY_free(pEVPPKey);
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
                                            }

                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
                        }
                        EC_KEY_free(pEcKey);
                    }
                    /*
                     * TODO: Remove end of #pragma above if adapted!
                     */
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
                    BN_CTX_free(pBigNumCtx);
                }
                else
                {
                    err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
                }
                BN_free(pBigNumPrivate);
            }
            else
            {
                err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
            }

            THREAD_UNLOCK_LIB_TOOLS();
        }
    }

    return err;
}
```

I have tried to replace the deprecated EC functions with the EVP key functions supported by OpenSSL 3.0. Here is my latest attempt:

```c
ERR Security_GetECKey(KeyPairECType enKeyPairECType, const unsigned char *puchKey, unsigned int uiLength, char **ppstPEMKey)
{
    ERR err;

    THREAD_INIT_LOCK_LIB_TOOLS();

    err = ERR_NONE;

    if((enKeyPairECType > KeyPairECType_Max) ||
       (ppstPEMKey == NULL) ||
       (uiLength == 0) ||
       (puchKey == NULL))
    {
        err = Err_Code(ERR_INVALID_PARAM);
    }
    else
    {
        const char *pstCurveName;

        switch(enKeyPairECType)
        {
            case KeyPairECType_NID_SECP521r1:
                pstCurveName = SN_secp521r1;
                break;
            default:
                pstCurveName = NULL;
                err = Err_Code(ERR_INVALID_PARAM);
                break;
        }

        if(err == ERR_NONE)
        {
            BIGNUM *pBigNumPrivate;

            THREAD_LOCK_LIB_TOOLS();
            /*
             * Use length from mpi header + 4. instead of length of whole char array.
             * Length of char array (uiLength) could be longer than mpi
             */
            pBigNumPrivate = BN_mpi2bn((unsigned char *) puchKey, ((puchKey[0] << 24) | (puchKey[1] << 16) | (puchKey[2] << 8) | puchKey[3]) + 4, NULL);
            if(pBigNumPrivate != NULL)
            {
                int iNid = OBJ_sn2nid(pstCurveName);
                if(iNid != NID_undef)
                {
                    EC_GROUP *pEcGroup = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(iNid);
                    if(pEcGroup != NULL)
                    {
                        EC_POINT *pEcPoint = EC_POINT_new(pEcGroup);
                        BN_CTX *pBigNumCtx = BN_CTX_new();
                        if((pEcPoint != NULL) && (pBigNumCtx != NULL) && EC_POINT_mul(pEcGroup, pEcPoint, pBigNumPrivate, NULL, NULL, pBigNumCtx))
                        {
                            size_t uzPubKeySize = EC_POINT_point2oct(pEcGroup, pEcPoint, POINT_CONVERSION_COMPRESSED, NULL, 0, NULL);
                            if(uzPubKeySize > 0)
                            {
                                unsigned char *puchPubKey = NULL;
                                err = Mem_AllocEx((void **) &puchPubKey, uzPubKeySize);
                                if((err == ERR_NONE) && (EC_POINT_point2oct(pEcGroup, pEcPoint, POINT_CONVERSION_COMPRESSED, puchPubKey, uzPubKeySize, NULL)))
                                {
                                    OSSL_PARAM_BLD *paramBuild = OSSL_PARAM_BLD_new();
                                    if((paramBuild != NULL) &&
                                       OSSL_PARAM_BLD_push_utf8_string(paramBuild, OSSL_PKEY_PARAM_GROUP_NAME, pstCurveName, 0) &&
                                       OSSL_PARAM_BLD_push_BN(paramBuild, OSSL_PKEY_PARAM_PRIV_KEY, pBigNumPrivate) &&
                                       OSSL_PARAM_BLD_push_octet_ptr(paramBuild, OSSL_PKEY_PARAM_ENCODED_PUBLIC_KEY, puchPubKey, uzPubKeySize))
                                    {
                                        EVP_PKEY *pEVPPKey = NULL;
                                        OSSL_PARAM *pParams = OSSL_PARAM_BLD_to_param(paramBuild);
                                        EVP_PKEY_CTX *pKeyCtx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_from_name(NULL, "EC", NULL);

                                        if((pParams != NULL) &&
                                           (pKeyCtx != NULL) &&
                                           (EVP_PKEY_fromdata_init(pKeyCtx) > 0) &&
                                           ((EVP_PKEY_fromdata(pKeyCtx, &pEVPPKey, EVP_PKEY_KEYPAIR, pParams)) > 0))
                                        {
                                            EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(pEVPPKey, NULL);
                                            if(EVP_PKEY_check(ctx) <= 0)
                                                ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);

                                            BIO *pBIOOut = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
                                            if(pBIOOut != NULL)
                                            {
                                                if((PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey(pBIOOut, pEVPPKey, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL)) == 0)
                                                {
                                                    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
                                                    err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    const unsigned char *puchPEMKey;
                                                    int iBIOLength = BIO_get_mem_data(pBIOOut, &puchPEMKey);
                                                    if(iBIOLength > 0)
                                                    {
                                                        err = Mem_AllocEx((void **) ppstPEMKey, (iBIOLength + 1) * sizeof(char));
                                                        if(err == ERR_NONE)
                                                        {
                                                            memcpy(*ppstPEMKey, puchPEMKey, iBIOLength);
                                                            (*ppstPEMKey)[iBIOLength] = '\00';
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                BIO_free(pBIOOut);
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
                                            }
                                            EVP_PKEY_free(pEVPPKey);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
                                        }
                                        EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(pKeyCtx);
                                        OSSL_PARAM_free(pParams);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
                                    }
                                    OSSL_PARAM_BLD_free(paramBuild);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
                                }
                                Mem_Free((void **) &puchPubKey);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
                        }
                        EC_POINT_free(pEcPoint);
                        BN_CTX_free(pBigNumCtx);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
                    }
                    EC_GROUP_free(pEcGroup);
                }
                else
                {
                    err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
            }
            BN_free(pBigNumPrivate);
        }
        else
        {
            err = Err_Code(ERR_TOOLS_SECURITY_GET_EC_KEY);
        }
        THREAD_UNLOCK_LIB_TOOLS();
    }
    return err;
}
```

It looks like I am not creating all the parameters of the EVP structure that are necessary to create the PEM key.
The check after the key generation returns the following error:

```
C01BFCF7FF7F0000:error:080C0102:elliptic curve routines:ossl_ec_key_public_check_quick:passed a null parameter:crypto/ec/ec_key.c:444:
```

After PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey, the following errors are finally output:

```
C01BFCF7FF7F0000:error:080C0102:elliptic curve routines:i2d_ECPrivateKey:passed a null parameter:crypto/ec/ec_asn1.c:1031:
C01BFCF7FF7F0000:error:1C8C0100:Provider routines:key_to_p8info:malloc failure:providers/implementations/encode_decode/encode_key2any.c:94:
```

I'm running out of ideas and the OpenSSL man page isn't really helpful, can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, the new high-level interface can't create a 'keypair' PKEY with the public derived from a raw private. What you can do is create a private-only PKEY and write that out -- this IS valid though not recommended, per RFC5915 aka SEC1, and software written by people who know what they're doing, like OpenSSL (in this case at least!), *will* read it. However, a lot of software is not written by such people and may reject or mishandle such a file. In that case, or if you just really want a keypair, what you can do is write the private-only key "out" to memory and read it "back in" -- *that* API *does* (internally) derive public from private, (edit)<s>resulting in</s> but it also sets the encoding flag to no-public, so you must fix that to get a PKEY you can write as a keypair.

Here is modified code covering both options. I *really* dislike the "if precondition1 if precondition2 if precondition3 ..." style that results in the code for the normal case, the one I usually care about, being indented so far right I have to go outside to my neighbor's house to read it (especially in winter weather like now), so I used trivial abort-on-error; you will almost certainly want to change this back to something that fits in your program design.

```c
// 75474348.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/core_names.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/param_build.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>

void fail (const char * str, int data)
{ fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d\n", str, data); ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr); exit(1); }

int main (void)
{
    // fake MPI input for testing
    unsigned char puchKey[4+66] = {0,0,0,66}; /* unsigned int uiLength */
    RAND_bytes(puchKey+4+1,66-1);

    const char *pstCurveName = SN_secp521r1;

    BIGNUM *pBigNumPrivate = BN_mpi2bn((unsigned char *) puchKey, ((puchKey[0] << 24) | (puchKey[1] << 16) | (puchKey[2] << 8) | puchKey[3]) + 4, NULL);
    if(pBigNumPrivate == NULL) fail("BN_mpi2bin",0);

    OSSL_PARAM_BLD *paramBuild = OSSL_PARAM_BLD_new();
    if((paramBuild == NULL) ) fail("OSSL_PARAM_BLD_new",0);
    if(!OSSL_PARAM_BLD_push_utf8_string(paramBuild, OSSL_PKEY_PARAM_GROUP_NAME, pstCurveName, 0) 
        ||!OSSL_PARAM_BLD_push_BN(paramBuild, OSSL_PKEY_PARAM_PRIV_KEY, pBigNumPrivate) 
        ||!OSSL_PARAM_BLD_push_int(paramBuild, OSSL_PKEY_PARAM_EC_INCLUDE_PUBLIC, 0/*no*/)
        ) fail("OSS_PARAM_BLD_push-3",0);
    OSSL_PARAM *pParams = OSSL_PARAM_BLD_to_param(paramBuild);
    EVP_PKEY_CTX *pKeyCtx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_from_name(NULL, "EC", NULL);
    EVP_PKEY *pEVPPKey = NULL;
    if((pParams == NULL) || (pKeyCtx == NULL) ) fail("OSSL_PARAM_BLD_to_param|EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_",0);
    if(EVP_PKEY_fromdata_init(pKeyCtx) <= 0
        ||EVP_PKEY_fromdata(pKeyCtx, &pEVPPKey, OSSL_KEYMGMT_SELECT_ALL_PARAMETERS|OSSL_KEYMGMT_SELECT_PRIVATE_KEY/*EVP_PKEY_KEYPAIR*/, pParams) <= 0 )
        fail("EVP_PKEY_fromdata-2",0);

#if want_to_convert_internally_to_include_private
    unsigned char buf[50+70], *ptr = buf;
    if( i2d_PrivateKey(pEVPPKey,&ptr) <= 0 ) fail("i2d",0);
    size_t len = ptr-buf; ptr = buf;
    if( !d2i_PrivateKey(EVP_PKEY_EC,&pEVPPKey,&ptr,len) ) fail("d2i",0);
    if( !EVP_PKEY_set_int_param(pEVPPKey,"include-public",1) ) fail("EVP_PKEY_set-include-public",0);
#endif

    BIO *pBIOOut = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    if(pBIOOut == NULL) fail("BIO_new",0);
    if((PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey(pBIOOut, pEVPPKey, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL)) == 0) fail("PEM_write_bio",0);
    const unsigned char *puchPEMKey;
    int iBIOLength = BIO_get_mem_data(pBIOOut, &puchPEMKey);
    if(iBIOLength <= 0) fail("BIO_get_mem_data",iBIOLength);
#if 0
    if( !(*ppstPEMKey = malloc (iBIOLength + 1)) ) abort();
    memcpy(*ppstPEMKey, puchPEMKey, iBIOLength);
    (*ppstPEMKey)[iBIOLength] = '\00';
#else // output to user for testing
    fwrite(puchPEMKey,1,iBIOLength,stdout);
#endif

    BIO_free(pBIOOut);
    EVP_PKEY_free(pEVPPKey);
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(pKeyCtx);
    OSSL_PARAM_free(pParams);
    OSSL_PARAM_BLD_free(paramBuild);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I managed to generate a PEM key using your code example, unfortunately this key differs from the expected PEM key. The expected key is significantly longer than the key I generate from the private key (383 vs. 188). As in your example I create the public key by exporting the EVP_Key and importing it again (section "want_to_convert_internally_to_include_private").

Comment: Schiggy: sorry, I didn't look carefully enough at my test data and missed a bit (almost literally!); see edit.